# Need help in understanding why '-' sign if an undefined operator in Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am writing a 3 Step AB Method code to output the computed solutions, time points and step sizes and a log-log plot of the errors. Whilst I input the Time Domain, RHS of the function, Initial Conditions and step sizes.

I am getting the following error, when trying to get my error term for the Log-Log plot and I don't know why:

**Undefined operator '-' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
Error in `AB32` (line 39)
`errAB3 = abs(y(i+2) - G);`**

I am putting the following in to the command window:

**`[y, t, h] = AB32([-1,2], @(t, y) -3*y+6*t+5, 2*exp(3)-1 , 39.1592, 39.1474, 10.^-4, @(t) 2*exp(-3*t)+2*t+1)`**

My code is the following:

```
% To solve y' = -3y+6t+5 s.t. y(-1) = 2exp(3)-1 for -1 <= t <= 2 using 
% 3-step Adams-Bashforth method.
%Inputs Below:
% Dom = Time Domain i.e. 2-(-1)=3
% f = RHS Function
% F = Initial Solution
% F2 = 2nd Step found using RK2
% F3 = 3rd Step found using RK2
% h = step size.
% G = Exact Solution

function [y, t, h] = AB32(dom, f, F, F2, F3, h, G)
f = @(t, y) -3*y + 6*t + 5; % RHS
T = diff(dom); % This is length of the time interval for which you're solving for, i.e. 2-0 = 2.
N = ceil(T/h); % total number of times steps
h = T/N;


% Preallocations:
t = zeros(N+1, 1); 
y = zeros(N+1, 1);

% Initializations:
y(1) = F; % Initial value of the ODE IVP

% Compute the values at point 2 & 3 using RK2 Method:
t(2) = -1+h;
y(2) = F2;

t(3) = -1+(2*h);
y(3) = F3;

% Main loop for marching N steps:
for i = 3:N
  t(i+3) = -1+(i-1)*h; % time points
  y(i+3) = y(i+2) + (h/12)*(23*f(t(i+2), y(i+2)) - (16*f(t(i+1), y(i+1))) + 5*f(t(i), y(i))); % 3-step Adams-Bashforth method!!!
end

%Find Error in Estimation
errAB3 = abs(y(i+2) - G);

%Plotting of Log-Log Plot
loglog(h, errAB3, '.-r', 'MarkerSize', 15)
legend('Error in Adams-Bashforth 3 Step Method')
xlabel('Step Size h')
ylabel('error at point x')
title('Error in Adams-Bashforth 3 Step Method')
```

Comment: Why are you redefining the right side `f` inside the integration function? Why are you using `i` outside the loop where it is properly defined? What value does it have, is `y(i+2)` even defined there?

Comment: so I need to remove line 12 so f is only defined when I input in to the command function. 

I need to change y(3) to y(i+2) and y(2) to y(i+1)? I am unsure as to where I need to move the loop? 

I then need to get the log-log plot to generate the graph with more than 1 step size, so I can show it has a 3rd order error. Can you help @LutzL please?

Comment: It would probably help if you separated the code into different `.m` files. One exclusively for the integration function `AB32`, and one for the main file where you control the input to `AB32` and process its output. This would remove the temptation of ill-defined loop variables and also the need to pass the exact solution `G` as parameter, as that is part of the output processing, not of the numerical integration.

Comment: This is a question I have been given in class and have spent some time trying to understand it. But my lecturer would like it in one code, we have no prior Matlab experience, so this is just my attempt and I am trying to keep it to one code.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know Matlab.

It appears that `G` is a function, and that you're supposed to pass a `t` value into it when using its results as a number. `y(i+2) - G(i+2)` or similar should work.

Comment: thank you it allows me to get answers now, the only problem I have is I can't get a graph plot for multiple step sizes. To show on the log-log plot has a 3rd order

Answer (score 0):

You program a function `integrate(..)` getting the relevant arguments, doing the start steps and the multi-step integration. This you have more or less done. Next you need a main loop over the different 'h', something like

```
M = 300
h = 0.1^linspace(2,6,M)
err = zeros(M,1)
for k =1:M
    [y,t] = integrate(...,h(k))
    err(k)=max(abs(y-G(t)))
end

loglog(h,err,...)
```

If you put everything in one file, do not forget to close subroutines with `end`.

Comment: sorry, thank you for the help but I still can't get it to work.